# Redis LRU as well as having keys expire individually?

Tags: redis

I currently have Redis as a LRU cache.  I want to keep this, but I also have some things I'm going to store in cache that are called often but are only valid for small amounts of time.

Can I use both?

So if I don't put a expiry on some keys, they will be evicted via the LRU algorithm, but will keys I set a expire on expire individually? Or do I have to deploy another redis database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you'll want to separate these to two independent instances, which is a good choice regardless.

Redis' eviction policy is determined by the `maxmemory-policy` configuration directive. It has two main "flavors" - all keys or volatile (i.e. with TTL) only. Since there is no eviction flavor for non-volatile keys only, you'll need to keep the current LRU cache instance with its `all-*` eviction policy and have another instance with `maxmemory-policy=none` for your TTLed keys.